# tableview with 3 sections crashed when scrolling down

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, tableview, sections

I am creating a tableview with 3 sections and each section is being populated from a Multidimentional NSMutableArray. The values are added to the mutable array but the app crashes every time i try to set texts to the labels in each section. Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"wsolna hon");
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HomeTableViewCell";
HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
int row= [indexPath row];


                if (indexPath.section == 0){
                     homeObject = [homeArray[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                        NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[homeObject.News dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
                    cell.NewsDateLabel.text= homeObject.News_Date;
                    cell.NewsLabel.attributedText= attrStr;
                    NSLog(@"news: %@", homeObject.News);

                }


                if (indexPath.section == 1){

                    homeObject = [homeArray[1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                   NSLog(@"value of indexpath for library: %d",row);
                   cell.NewsLabel.text= homeObject.Library_text;
                   cell.TestimonialNameLabel.text= @"";
                NSLog(@"Library: %@", homeObject.Library_text);
            }

                if (indexPath.section == 2){
                    homeObject = [homeArray[2] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                     NSLog(@"news: %@",homeObject.Testimonial_Description);
                     cell.NewsLabel.text= homeObject.Library_text;
                     cell.TestimonialNameLabel.text = homeObject.Testimonial_Name;
                    NSLog(@"Testimonial: %@", homeObject.Testimonial_Description);

            }



  return cell;
 }
```

//here is where the NSMutable array is being filled
     - (void) getDataFromDb
     {

```
NSString * paths=[self getWritableDBPath];

const char *dbpath =  [paths UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
static sqlite3 *database = nil;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM homedata", nil];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    //  NSLog(@"Databasae opened = %@", userN);

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {


            NSString *modID= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            NSString *nDate = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
            NSString *nText = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSString *dText = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSString *tText = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSString *tName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

            if ([modID isEqualToString:@"77"]){
              //  NSLog(@"News found: %@", nText);
                [homeArray[0] addObject:[[Home alloc]initWithItemID: modID andNewsName:nText andNewsDate: (NSString *) nDate andLibraryText: dText andTestDescription: tText andTestimonialName: (NSString *) tName]];
            } else if ([modID isEqualToString:@"81"]){
                [homeArray[1] addObject:[[Home alloc]initWithItemID: modID andNewsName:nText andNewsDate: (NSString *) nDate andLibraryText: dText andTestDescription: tText andTestimonialName: (NSString *) tName]];
              //   NSLog(@"Library found: %@", dText);
            } else if ([modID isEqualToString:@"78"]){
                [homeArray[2] addObject:[[Home alloc]initWithItemID: modID andNewsName:nText andNewsDate: (NSString *) nDate andLibraryText: dText andTestDescription: tText andTestimonialName: (NSString *) tName]];
              //   NSLog(@"News found: %@", tText);
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    //  NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
 }
```

and in ViewDidLoad i have:

```
homeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init], [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], nil];
```

and also:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"woslit 3al 1");
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT count(*) FROM homedata where module_ID= 77"];
    return [self countcells:querySQL];
}
if(section == 1)
{
      NSLog(@"woslit 3al 2");
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT count(*) FROM homedata where module_ID= 78"];
    return  [self countcells:querySQL];
}

if (section == 2)
{
     NSLog(@"woslit 3al 3");
  return[self countcells:@"SELECT count(*) FROM homedata where module_ID= 81"];
}
 else return 0;
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

//TEMP SECTION STRING HOLDER:
NSString *sectionHeader = nil;


//SET TITLE FOR EACH SECTION:
if(section == 0) {
    sectionHeader = @"News";
}

if(section == 1) {
    sectionHeader = @"TYM Library";
}

if(section == 2) {
    sectionHeader = @"Testimonial";
}
```

I am able to get the values when i use NSLog. but when i  slide down it crashes.
Can someone please check where the problem might be?
Thanks!

Comment: what is your error message for crash?

Comment: this is the error: [Home objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1092a9f10

Comment: there is problem in your array's data. it is not getting any data on that index.

Comment: Exception breakpoint would help you

Comment: I am using NSLog to display all my data.. all is being displayed and on the breakpoint there is no error. However when i slide down it crashes immediately

Comment: try to put NSLog on this two and check output 1- NSLog(@"data on one is :%@",[homeArray[1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); same for homeObject = [homeArray[2] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Which line does the code crash on? Please use breakpoints to find the offending statement. What is `Home`?

Comment: i used breakpoints now... it is crashing at this line: HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: when i scroll down it crashes on this line

Comment: That's not the line it is crashing at. I don't think you know how to use breakpoints.

Comment: ahh it's crashing here:  homeObject = [homeArray[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Looks to me like your model data is not an array of arrays, but instead at least one of the top-level array elements is a `Home` object.  I cannot confirm without seeing the code that populates the model object.

Comment: That code looks ok (`homeArray` doesn't need to be mutable BTW).  Show the datasource methods that return the number of sections and rows in the data object.

Comment: ok i edited the code again

Comment: Check your code for a line where you accidentally set `homeArray[i] = someObjectOfClassHome` or for a line where you are trying to access a home object's index: `[someObjectOfClassHome objectAtIndex:i]` i.e. `someObjectOfClassHome[i]`. It is definitely better practice to return your array size in the method `numberOfRowsInSection` as suggested by @Droppy but I do not believe that this will solve your problem. Nor do I believe that the error is in the code you posted but hidden somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` datasource delegate method should be returning the number of elements in the sub-arrays of `homeArray` and not from the database.  This is both much quicker and avoids issues where the database and the in-memory version of the data get out-of-sync:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [homeArray[section] count];
}
```

Comment: @ralph Did you take a look at the comment from Mischa on your question?

Comment: While this is a good suggestion, it is not the one causing the issue.